# PulseAudio sink missing for GSP670 headset

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I just got a Sennheiser GSP 670 gaming headset and I had some issues with the device being detected correctly by PulseAudio.

The headset is wireless and it has a dongle.

The headset has a main stereo output for games and music. Apart from that, there is one more mono input and output that is dedicated to communication.

Essentially there are two audio devices registered by ALSA (and on Windows as well), one which can be used for stereo playback and another one which can be used for mono playback and capture at the same time.

The dongle is registered as follows

```
hw:S60,0
hw:S60,1
```

The hedset is registered as follows when it's plugged in via USB

```
hw:G670,0
hw:G670,1
```

I have no trouble using the devices with ALSA, however PulseAudio only detects the first device, which is for communication and not the other one.

The way I solved it for now is by telling PulseAudio to ignore the device and creating the sinks manually.

Here is how I make PulseAudio ignore the device with an udev rule:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1395", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0089", ENV{PULSE_IGNORE}="1"
```

And this is the script I am using to create the sinks and sources:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/sh

pacmd load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:S70,0 name=gsa70_comm_output
pacmd 'update-sink-proplist alsa_output.gsa70_comm_output device.description="GSA70 Communication" '

pacmd load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:S70,1 name=gsa70_main
pacmd 'update-sink-proplist alsa_output.gsa70_main device.description="GSA70 Main" '

pacmd load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:S70,0 name=gsa70_comm_input
pacmd 'update-source-proplist alsa_input.gsa70_comm_input device.description="GSA70 Communication" '
```

This is working so far but it's not optimal. It's not plug and play, meaning the sinks are still there after the dongle is disconnected.

I could use udev to run this script when the the dongle is connected, and then run a cleanup script when the dongle is disconnected, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: I ended up solving this with a custom PulseAudio profile: https://github.com/szszoke/sennheiser-gsp670-pulseaudio-profile